# How do I run etop towards an erlang node with a fully qualified name?

Tags: debugging, erlang

When I start etop on my machine I get the following error message:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2011::11:30:09 ===
** System NOT running to use fully qualified hostnames **
** Hostname selilsx074.lmera.ericsson.se is illegal **
Error Couldn't connect to node 'gil@selilsx074.lmera.ericsson.se'
```

I'm thinking that the problem is that the etop process is starting with a short name (-sname) and therefore is unable to communicate with the process I want to monitor, which is started with a fully qualified long name (-name).

How do I start the etop process with a long name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since the start script for etop looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="etop"
erl -sname $NAME -hidden -s etop -s erlang halt -output text $@
```

I guess I'm out of luck using that. I have to write my own start script if I want to use a fully qualified name, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="etop"
erl -name $NAME -hidden -s etop -s erlang halt -output text $@
```

Comment: [entop](https://github.com/mazenharake/entop) handles that nicely by allowing you to use the `-sname` and `-name` flags directly to the program.